Discovered a new primality test. Is it 100% accurate?
To test whether an integer $n$ is prime:
STEP 1: If $n$ is an odd integer, proceed to the next step.
STEP 2: Calculate the following expression:
$
E(n)= \frac{1}{16}(a^n + a^{-n})(b^n + b^{-n})
$,
where,
$
a=\tan{9^\circ}=1+\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{5+2\sqrt{5}}
$
$
b=\tan{27^\circ}=-1+\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{5-2\sqrt{5}}
$
Evaluate the expression $E(n)\mod n $.
If $E(n)\mod n = 1 $, then $n$ is a prime number. Otherwise, $n$ is not prime.
I verified this test using Wolfram Alpha over a large range of numbers. Can this become a 100% accurate primality test? (exempting 2, which is not odd.)

Where did this come from? Why do you expect it to work? Can you say something about the reasoning behind the formula?

I have no idea why this works as a primality test. It just works.

It turns out that $E(2)=\frac{41}4$. Are you claiming that $\frac{41}4\mod2=1$? If so, what does this equality mean?

You can't take $E(even)$.

It should work for all odd primes.

Right. I missed that you wrote that $n$ is odd.

I don't understand why is this being downvoted.. Anyway, I'll maybe give it a try to understand why this seems to be the case.

Just for context: look at the minimal polynomials of both the values $a$ and $b$ and try to understand how the products and exponential can be recursively calculated. I suspect it should be easy (if true!) to show it is not 1 in non primes.

@BihariLal I'm not asking you why it works, I'm asking you why you think it might?  Did you pick two random numbers out of nowhere and numerically test if there was something that happened when n was or wasn't prime? Are you trying to generalize something else that you had seen? Where do the constants in the problem come from? You can't simply say "I tested it and it seemed to work," you had to have come up with it to try to test it first.

Actually, I was working with $a$ and $b$ to observe modular patterns in $E(n)$. Accidentally, I discovered this could become a primality test.

@BihariLal You were working with those specific $a$ and $b$?  With lots of different ones?  Were you looking at dozens of different formulas? If not, why those specific $a$ and $b$? Why this particular formula? Why were you even in a position to make this hypothesis?

I observed that all the prime factors of $E(n)$ end with the digit $1$. So, I thought maybe it is connected to prime numbers. I chose these specific $a$ and $b$ because I love to observe patterns using random things. I'm just a teen, I don't know advance maths.

This looks similar to  Lucas pseudoprimes, but with a sequence of degree $4$ instead of $2$. For some Lucas sequences the first pseudoprimes are pretty big, so a similar thing could be happening here. Up to which value of $n$ did you test?

How far have you tested the primality ?

I tested upto 67, beyond which Wolfram Alpha wasn't showing any results. However, it showed results for Carmichael Numbers 561,1729,1105, for which the result was not 1, hence these three numbers are not prime.

I'm voting to reopen this, otherwise I can ask this myself as a follow up question. But OP must tell me some context that I must add in order to make the post better.

Sorry sir, I have no idea what context could be added to make the post better.

$E(671) \equiv 1 \pmod  {671}$ but $671 = 11\times 16$

These are the counterexamples for $n<10000$: $671, 961, 1045, 1769, 2285, 2501$

In terms of the Golden Ratio $\phi:=\frac12(\sqrt{5}+1)$, we have ...
$$a^{\pm1} =\phi\left(2\mp\sqrt{4-\phi^{-2}}\right)\qquad b^{\pm1} = \phi^{-1}\left(2\mp\sqrt{4-\phi^2}\right)$$
Thus, upon expanding $a^n+a^{-n}$ and $b^n+b^{-n}$, terms with odd powers of the radical cancel; and, of course, terms with even powers of the radical no longer have the radical! Moreover, considering that the $E$-function multiplies these sums (and hence matching powers of their leading factors, which cancel in the product), you could restructure the definition in a way that drops those leading factors.
